# ionic2 - app suddenly not working properly

Tags: ionic2

I was working on an ionic2 app for around 4 to 5 days and suddenly at one point, the app started to behave abnormally.

- Setting the date fields don't work anymore
- the tabs don't change color when I navigate
- `*ngFor` don't work properly anymore

I even reverted to an old commit and it still did not work. I even removed and installed ionic from my system.

However when i run `ionic serve`, I see many `main.js` files like `0.main.js`, `1.main.js`, `2.main.js`

Comment: If you are minifying your code, maybe try to stop it and re-build. Just speculating really.

Answer (score 1):

can you share your files if possible ? `package.json` this may be due to some dependencies, try removing plugins and re-install them. If this doesn't work try adding removing platforms.